# Modelling indefinitely-recurring tasks in a schedule (calendar-like rails app)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database-design, architecture

This has been quite a stumbling block. Warning: the following is not a question, rather explanation of what I came up with. My question is — do you have a better way to do this? Is there some common technique for this that I'm not familiar with? Seems like this is a trivial problem.

So you have Task model. You can create tasks, complete them, destroy them. Then you have recurring tasks. It's just like regular task, but it has a recurrence rule attached to it. However, tasks can recur indefinitely — you can go a year ahead in the schedule, and you should see the task show up.

So when a user creates a recurring task, you don't want to build thousands of tasks for hundred years into the future, and save them to database, right? So I started thinking — how do you create them?

One way would be to create them as you view your schedule. So, when the user is moving a month ahead, any recurring tasks will be created. Of course that means that you can't simply work with database records of tasks any longer. Every SELECT operation on tasks you ever do has to be in the context of a particular date range, in order to trigger recurring tasks in that date range to persist. This is a maintenance and performance burden, but doable.

Alright, but how about the original task? Every recurrent task gets associated with the recurrence rule that created it, and every recurrence rule needs to know the original task that started the recurrence. The latter is important, because you need to clone the original task into new dates as the user browses their schedule. I guess doable too.

But what happens if the original task is updated? It means that now as we browse the schedule, we will be creating recurring tasks cloned off of the modified task. That's undesirable. All the implicitly persisted recurring tasks should show up the way the original task looked like when recurrence was added. So we need to store a copy of the original task separately, and clone from that, in order for recurrence to work.

However, when the user navigates the tasks in the schedule, how do we know if at a particular point a new recurrence task needs to be created? We ask recurrence rule: "hey, should I persist a task for this day?" and it says yes or no. If there is already a task for this recurrence for this day, we don't create one. All nice, except a user shall also be able to simply delete one of the recurring tasks that has been automatically persisted. In that case following our logic, the system will re-create the task that has been deleted. Not good. So it means we need to keep storing the task, but mark it as deleted task for this recurrence. Meh.

As I said in the beginning, I want to know if somebody else tackled this problem and can provide architectural advice here. Does it have to be this messy? Is there anything more elegant I'm missing?

**Update**: Since this question is hard to answer perfectly, I will approve the most helpful insight into design/architecture, which has the best helpfulness/trade-offs ratio for this type of problem. It does not have to encompass all the details.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I know this is an old question but I'm just starting to look into this for my own application and I found this paper by Martin Fowler illuminating: [Recurring Events for Calendars](http://martinfowler.com/apsupp/recurring.pdf)

The main takeaway for me was using what he calls "temporal expressions" to figure out if a booking falls on a certain date range instead of trying to insert an infinite number of events (or in your case tasks) into the database.

Practically, for your use case, this might mean that you store the Task with a "temporal expression" property called `schedule`. The [ice_cube recurrence gem](https://github.com/seejohnrun/ice_cube) has the ability to serialize itself into an active record property [like so](https://github.com/seejohnrun/ice_cube/wiki/IceCube-and-Rails):

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  include IceCube
  serialize :schedule, Hash

  def schedule=(new_schedule)
    write_attribute(:schedule, new_schedule.to_hash)
  end

  def schedule
    Schedule.from_hash(read_attribute(:schedule))
  end
end
```

Ice cube seems really flexible and even allows you to specify exceptions to the recurrence rules. (Say you want to delete just one occurrence of the task, but not all of them.)

The problem is that you can't really query the database for a task that falls in a specific range of dates, because you've only stored the rule for making tasks, not the tasks themselves. For my case, I'm thinking about adding a property like "next_recurrence_date" which will be used to do some basic sorting/filtering. You could even use that to throw a task on a queue to have something done on the next recurring date. (Like check if that date has passed and then regenerate it. You could even store an "archived" version of the task once its next recurring date passes.)

This fixes your issue with "what if the task is updated" since tasks aren't ever persisted until they're in the past.

Anyway, I hope that is helpful to someone trying to think this through for their own app.

Answer (score 4):

Having done a calendar-like component for an internal social networking app, here's my approach to that problem.

Tiny bit of background: I needed to book boardrooms for meetings for the entire company. Every boardroom needed to be booked either as a one-off or on a recurring basis. As you've found out, it's the recurrence rules that kill you. The additional twist to my problem was that there could be conflicts, i.e. two people could try to book the same boardroom for the same date and time.

I split my models into Boardroom (obviously) and Event (which is the booking associated to a User). I think there was a join model, as well, but it's been a while. When a User would try to book a boardroom, this is the process taken:

1. Attempt to book on the first available date (done through the calendar UI by the user similar to how Google Calendar creates events)
2. If it's a one-off, you're done
3. If it's a recurring event, try to immediately book the next 6 events based on the rule given (weekly, bi-weekly, monthly); If it fails, due to conflict, book the ones you can, e-mail the conflicts to the user
4. Book for the next year or up to the date the recurrence is ending in a background job; Follow the conflict resolution rule from #3

When resolving the conflicts, the user had the option of either resolving them on a case-by-case basis or moving the remaining bookings to the new, available date and time.

If the user updated the original booking (e.g changed the time and date), he/she had the option of updating only the that one or every following recurrence. If the latter was selected, steps 3 and 4 are re-invoked after the deletion of existing events.

If this sounds a lot like Google Calendar, then you've fully understood my approach, :)

Hope this helps.

Comment: The key of your advice (as applies to the question) seems to be in "book for the next year [...] in a background job". This is interesting. You pick an arbitrary reasonable limit and persist as far as that limit. This solves the issue of not having records physically available in the database. However, it feels iffy since what if you need to run some kind of calculation or report that reaches beyond your reasonable limit? What happens when current date approaches the end of year? Do you then create more records for another year? Etc.

Comment: Yes, I set up two background jobs. One does the scheduling for the newly created event, the other was a daily task that checked whether or not more events were needed. If a recurring event that had no end date had fewer than 5 events left, I'd kick off another batch of saves.

As far as reporting is concerned, I had no such requirements at that time. Basically, all I had to show is the last date of the current recurring event. You'd have to take care not to overreach the date if that's requirement, for sure.

Answer (score 1):

I personally think that (in python which I know well), and ruby (which I know less well, but it's a dynamic language, and so I think the concepts map 1:1), you should be using generators.  How's that for a minimalistic answer?  Now, when you generate your UI, you pass in a reference to the generator, and it generates the objects you need, as they are requested.

As an interface, it has next item, and previous item methods, and acts a bit like a cursor that can wade forward and backward through the various interations. It is in fact, a piece of code masquerading as an infinite series (array) without using infinite memory.

Why do you need to proliferate objects? What you really need are virtual data display controls (for the web or desktop) also known as "paging" I think, in web contexts, and you can think of your schedule as an infinite generated-on-demand spreadsheet, with no top row, and no bottom row.  The only values you need to be able to calculate (calculate, not store) are the ones that appear right now, as visible to the user.

Comment: This pretty much agrees with what I wrote. The downside is that you can't simply work with task records (for calculations, reporting, etc), since the recurrent ones are not physically stored yet. You have to have some date range which governs the creation of recurring tasks for that range.

Comment: Coming back and re-reading this stuff 8 years later, I think this answer is the most insightful one, but was a difficult advice to take at the time.